# Benifits / disadvantages of Chrooting NGINX and not PHP

Tags: nginx

I have recently chrooted NGINX and it works well, but I am having trouble chrooting php and mysql along with it, it is really nessasery? What are the benefits / disadvantages weighed up here?

Comment: Why did you chroot nginx if you didn't know why you were doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look at it this way.  By chrooting Nginx, you have prevented it from accessing files outside of what it's supposed to.  This would help you in the event that *Nginx* is compromised.

The problem is, if PHP is not chrooted, it's possible to use Nginx to pass an exploit to PHP to gain access to the machine.  They could for example tell PHP to execute any arbitrary file that it has access to.  PHP will happily do so, and tell them the contents of the file (assuming it doesn't have any PHP code within).

So, you aren't gaining a whole lot by chrooting Nginx without PHP. You are more likely to get compromised through an exploit in the software you are running on top of PHP then you are via Nginx.